# Magic Mouse 2 jump-scrolling erraneously in Windows (Boot Camp)

Tags: windows, macos, mouse, boot-camp, scrolling

My brand new Magic Mouse 2 works nicely in OSX, but in Windows 10, it detects scrolling gestures when there really are none, as if there was a sensitivity problem or a lack of sensible margin of error when detecting movements. E.g., it happens frequently that when I try to left- or right-click something on a page, a scroll is detected right before I click and the button jumps out of sight; when I'm lucky, it happens after clicking. Same with larger mouse movements - the movements of my hand on the mouse surface seem to immediately trigger a scroll, but it doesn't happen that way in OSX. And when I try to Ctrl-click a link on a webpage for opening it in a tab, a scroll is detected most often and the page is zoomed in or out wildly, which is really annoying.

Does anyone have a similar problem and/or a solution to it without disabling the scrolling altogether, as it's really handy when it works?

Comment: Specifically what Mac & what OS?

Comment: macOS Sierra 10.12.2 on iMac 27" Retina 5K MK482D/A, and Windows 10

Comment: Best I can come up with is to reinstall the drivers you get when you run the bootcamp assistant, but I can't test so can't provide any kind of real answer.

Comment: thx, appreciate it, but I forgot to mention that it's already my 2nd Windows installation on this machine due to license problems on 1st, and the problem occured both times.